# ActionListener for multi-dimensional array only works for first button?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array, actionlistener

I am attempting to create a grid of 12x12 of JButtons, and then randomly assign ten of the buttons to have a "gold nugget" underneath, each time you run the program. When you click a button that has a nugget underneath, it should change the text of the button to "NUGGET," and if you click one that doesn't have a nugget, it should change the text to "Missed!" I've gotten the grid set up, and the buttons, but I can't figure out what is going on with the ActionListener, and why it is only changing the first button (which would be [1][1] in the multi-dimensional array) no matter what button you click, it will just change buttons[1][1] to "Missed!" Here is the code for my JPanel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel{

    private JButton[][]buttons;
    private final int size = 12;
    private GridLayout experimentLayout;
    private int clicked;
    private int k = 0;
    private int j = 0;
    private int max = 11;
    private int min = 0;
    private int randomNum1;
    private int randomNum2;
    public Random rand = new Random();

    public Panel(){

        experimentLayout =  new GridLayout(size,size);
        setLayout(experimentLayout);
        buttons = new JButton[size][size];

        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                 buttons[k][j] = new JButton("o");
                 add(buttons[k][j]);

              }
        }

        ArrayList<JButton> nuggetButtonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            randomNum1 = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            randomNum2 = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            nuggetButtonList.add((JButton)buttons[randomNum1][randomNum2]);
            System.out.println(nuggetButtonList);
        }




        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  if(nuggetButtonList.contains((JButton)e.getSource())){
                      buttons[k][j].setText("NUGGET.");
                  } else {
                      buttons[k][j].setText("Missed!");
                  }
            }
        };

        buttons[k][j].addActionListener(listener);

    }

}
```

And the code for the Driver:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Dig for nuggets~!");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Panel nuggetGraphics = new Panel();
        nuggetGraphics.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 1000));
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(nuggetGraphics, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be re-randomizing things each time the ActionListener is pressed which does not sound like what your requirement calls for.

Instead, you should assign the random buttons **once** in your constructor and not in the ActionListener. Perhaps create a `List<JButton>` that holds all of the selecteed nugget buttons, and then in the ActionListener, if the source JButton is held by the list (`if nuggetButtonList.contains(sourceButton)`), then show the user that it is a Nugget button.

For example, consider giving your program **two** `List<JButton>`:

```
List<JButton> allButtons = new ArrayList<>();
List<JButton> selectedButtons  = new ArrayList<>();
```

The first to hold all the buttons, the second only the selected ones.

In your constructor, fill the allButtons list as you create your buttons, and add your ActionListener to each button. Then shuffle the allButtons list and use the shuffled list to fill your selected buttons list. e.g.,

```
  MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        JButton button = new JButton(DEFAULT);
        button.addActionListener(myListener);
        add(button);
        allButtons.add(button);
     }
  }
  Collections.shuffle(allButtons);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUGGET_COUNT; i++) {
     selectedButtons.add(allButtons.get(i));
  }
```

then in your ActionListener, simply check if the button is in the selected list:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
     if (selectedButtons.contains(source)) {
        source.setText(NUGGET);
        source.setBackground(Color.yellow);
     } else {
        source.setText(MISSED);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense. I've tried to change it, but it still doesn't seem to be working - I'm not certain why, though.

Comment: @Sarah: `"it still doesn't seem to be working"` does not give us enough information to allow us to help. What exactly is your code now doing?

Comment: @Sarah: Be sure to **create** your JButtons **before** trying to randomize or add them to the List. Otherwise you're adding nothing but nulls to the List!

Comment: What it is doing is giving the same output. It's not giving any errors, but none of the buttons will change text except for the first one. The first one will change to "Missed!"

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the problem where it was just nulls. It's still not changing any but the first button.

Comment: @Sarah: show your latest code as an edit to your question please.

Comment: @Sarah: please show the whole thing if not too big, in one **compilable** code file (your current code as I have copied it will not compile).

Comment: @Sarah: you're not adding ActionListeners to all the buttons. This must be done in the for loop where you create them. You're only adding the lister to button 0, 0.

Comment: Added the code for the driver, and updated the code for the JPanel. Those two sets of code, in different classes, should be compilable now.

Comment: @Sarah: see my comment above.

Comment: If I add ActionListeners to the buttons in the for loop where I create them, I get an error, because I haven't initialized the listener yet. What do I do to avoid that?

Comment: Initialize the listener first.

Comment: But then I get an error, because I haven't filled the nuggetButtonList yet. And I can't fill the nuggetButtonList, because I need to create the buttons before putting them into the nuggetButtonList.